# Refresh only CERTAIN mapped data from API - not all

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I fetched some data from an API. Then I mapped it as a div ( each div is a different piece of data ).

The data is dynamic, as it's being constantly updated/changed. I wanted to ask if it's possible to "refresh" the data, but only for the current div and not the other divs.

Example of how the mapped div's would look like in theory:

```
<>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div> (For example: user clicks to update data for this specific div -> then fetch current/updated data, and only update this div, not ALL other ones.. another option is to update data automatically all the time without having to refresh manually )
<div></div>
</>
```

```
function FetchCrypto() {

  const [coins, setCoins] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false'
      )
      .then(res => {
        setCoins(res.data);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }, []); 

// I guess I could write some kind of function here (within the useEffect) 
// or write a separate useEffect call to fetch data for "coins.id" 
// and then pass a dependency to see if state of coins.id changes ? 
// not really sure if that's a viable solution 

return (

{coins.map(coin => {
        
        return (
          (coin.id ? (
            <div>
            <img src={coin.image} alt='crypto' />
            <h1>{coin.name}</h1>
            <p className='stockPrice'>${coin.current_price.toFixed(2)}</p>
  
            {coin.price_change_percentage_24h < 0 ? (
              <p className='coin-percent redPercent'>{coin.price_change_percentage_24h.toFixed(2)}%</p>
            ) : (
              <p className='coin-percent greenPercent'>{coin.price_change_percentage_24h.toFixed(2)}%</p>
            )}
            
            <button className="deleteBtnCoin" removecoin={coin.id} onClick={removeHandler}>x</button>
            <button className="refreshBtnCoin"></button> // I already have prepared a button for it, but I need to figure out if it's possible
        </div> 
        ) : ( 
        <div key={coin.id}> </div>) 
        )) 
      })}      
)
```

Please let me know if it makes sense, I tried to make it simple and to the point - otherwise I will update the question.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to refresh the data for specific div element ? Any performance reason or just to make it simple ?

Comment: its an app that shows data for stock/crypto market.. and prices change every second, so I thought i'd make it possible to refresh/update prices with a simple refresh button - without having to fetch current data for everything

Comment: You're gonna have to refetch the whole thing sadly. That's how REST api's work. Graphql solves this so called overfetching issue.

Comment: @kevin interesting - i didnt know that, thanks a lot! i might look into graphql next time i'm working on a similar project :)